# issue on add button became disabled after alert message pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

im having problem on my add button... i want a condition that if there is a identical data in the grid the alert message pops up if the add button clicks. but it happens after the alert message pops up the add button will disabled. im stuck in this issue for days. thanks to someone that will help.

html:

```
<div class="main">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AvailabilitySave", "Worker", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AvailabilityForm" }))

        {

            <input type="hidden" id="availabilityId" name="workerId" value="@workerId" />

          <p>
                    <label for="dllAvailableDay">
                        <abbr title="This is a required field.">
                            <em><font color="red">*</font></em></abbr>
                        Available Day</label>
                    <span>
                        @Html.DropDownList("dllAvailableDay", new SelectList(ViewBag.availableDayList, "ID", "Display_Value", workerAvailableDay), "[Please Select]",
              new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                    })
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="TpStartTime">
                        <abbr title="This is a required field.">
                            <em><font color="red">*</font></em></abbr>
                        Start Time</label>
                    <span>
                        <input id="tpStartTime" name ="tpStartTime" value="@workerStartTime" 
                               style="padding:0 0 0 0 !important" />
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="TpEndTime">
                        <abbr title="This is a required field.">
                            <em><font color="red">*</font></em></abbr>
                        End Time</label>
                    <span>
                        <input id="tpEndTime" name ="tpEndTime" value="@workerEndTime" 
                                style="padding:0 0 0 0 !important"/>
                    </span>
                  </p>
    <p>
                    <label>
                        Anytime</label>
                    <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chAnytime" id="chAnytime" value="true" checked="checked" />
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span>
                        <input type="submit" id="addAvailBtn" class="styledButton" value="Add" />
                    </span>
                </p>
}
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#AvailabilityForm").on('submit', function (e) {

        var gvDetDDLs = $('#availabilityGrid').find("input[name=dllEditAvailableDay]");
        $.each(gvDetDDLs, function () {
            var duplicateExists = false;
            var ddlDay = $("#dllAvailableDay option:selected").text();
            var currVal = $(this).val();

            gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function () {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (ddlDay == currVal) {
                    duplicateExists = true;
                    $(this).focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
            if (duplicateExists) {
                alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                return false;
                $('#addAvailBtn').prop('disabled', false);
            }

        });
        return true;
    });
```

grid:

```
$("#availabilityGrid").kendoGrid({
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Worker/GetAvailabilityList?availabilityId=' + availabilityId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            change: function (e) {
                $(window.location.hash).click();
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#availabilityTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
        altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#availabilityTemplate").html())
    });
```

controller:

```
private void GetAvailableDayList()
        {
            var availableDayList = (from a in db.Lookups
                                    where a.Domain == "AVAILABLEDAY"
                                    select a).ToList();

            ViewBag.AvailableDayList = availableDayList;
        }
```